# Custom Mail Composer View Controller for iOS

Tags: ios, email, three20, viewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to have a mail composer view in my app but with a few extra fields and stuff. Since the original view controller Apple provides, `MFMailComposeViewController` doesn't allow any way to customize it.

So after a little bit of researching I came across the [Three20 framework](http://three20.info/) for iOS which provides a view controller called [TTMessageController](http://facebook.github.io/three20/api/Classes/TTMessageController.html) suits my needs. But I did some some checking on this framework and the feedback I've been reading doesn't sound too good. I even tried downloading, following the instructions to add it in a project but that ended up throwing errors also.

My question is, are there any other alternatives to the Three20's TTMessageController? I want to have a view controller where I can add some more input fields to customize it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Three20 is completely outdated and not suitable for use in a modern Xcode project (using ARC and all the new Objective C features from the last 2 years). Three20 has a very large dependency chain, and you will find yourself stuck trying to make sense of its class heirarchy just to accomplish simple things.

Also, as you correctly pointed out, `MFMailComposeViewController` cannot be customized in any way other than what is documented by Apple.

The only way to achieve what you want is to start from scratch with an empty UIViewController, and add the text fields you need - either programmatically, or using XIBs or using Storyboards.

I realize this answer doesn't provide you any new information but at least this confirms your feeling that using Three20 for this is a bad idea.